# ZenCart Paypal Pro Error 0

Tags: paypal, zen-cart

I'm trying to intergrate paypal pro onto my site 1.3.8a

Doing some test transactions, I'm being taken back to step two with a red warning at the top saying 0. However I can see my transactions are actually going through.

Obviously need to sort this out as the site is live.. Panic!!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from Zen-Cart forum:

http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?p=983373#post983373

Comment: As someone also said in that thread you mentioned, you should probably try to upgrade your Zen Cart to the latest 1.3.9x. It really has hundreds of fixes and improvements for the Paypal payment modules.